Firebase Function not running correctly, receiving "[firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND" error
I'm trying to validate a user's subscription by calling a Firebase Function from my Flutter app. The function works perfectly when I use its URL directly, but when I try to call it using httpsCallable, I get the following error in the terminal:
[firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND
What I'm trying to achieve:
I want to use httpsCallable to call a Firebase Function that validates the user's subscription. This function is hosted in the us-central1 region.
Problem:
The Firebase Function returns the error [firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND when called through httpsCallable.
However, if I use the function's URL directly, it works as expected.
Relevant code:
Firebase Function:
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.validateSubscription = functions
  .region('us-central1')
  .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const { uid } = data;
    if (!uid) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'invalid-argument',
        'User ID is missing'
      );
    }

    // Mock response for simplicity
    return { success: true, uid };
  });


Flutter (Dart) Client-Side Code:
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

Future<void> validateUserSubscription() async {
  try {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    if (user == null) {
      throw Exception("User not logged in");
    }

    final callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1')
        .httpsCallable('validateSubscription');
    final response = await callable.call({'uid': user.uid});

    print("Subscription validation successful: ${response.data}");
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error during subscription validation: $e");
  }
}

What I’ve tried:
Verified that the Firebase Function is deployed to the us-central1 region:
Deployed using firebase deploy.
Confirmed it appears in the Firebase console under Cloud Functions.
Verified the function URL works directly:
Copying and pasting the function's URL in Postman returns the correct result.
Added the region parameter when initializing the callable function:
FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'us-central1')

Checked that my Flutter app is connected to Firebase:
Firebase Authentication is working.
Firestore and other Firebase services are functional.
Searched for similar issues:
I found this solution suggesting the region mismatch might be the issue, but even with matching regions, the problem persists.
Error Logs:
[firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND

# Stack Trace
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:648:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:22:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      validateUserSubscription (package:my_app/main.dart:130:22)


**Why does the function return
[firebase_functions/not-found] NOT_FOUND 

when using httpsCallable, but works with the URL?
Are there any additional configurations needed for httpsCallable to work correctly with Firebase Functions?**
